# Set conditional formatting for a matching number across a workbook based on the value of a cell in one sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a list of phone numbers that get randomly assigned to a set number of sales staff.  The random list is copied to a sheet titled with their name.  When they call a number, they have a status column where they select the outcome of the call.

Based on that selection, the cell with the phone number changes to a specific color: Green for a sale; , Red for no sale; Yellow for call back.

I aim for all cells with that phone number across the workbook to change to color as well based on that selection.

Comment: Please add information about your workbook and what you have tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why are there duplicated cells for the same phone numbers in the first place? Don't you want to have each phone number in its own row one time only? Also, please add a sample of your sheet, how it looks and what the ranges are.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR:

The primary way to update the conditional formatting for all instances of a value across sheets based on a value that can be manually updated in any sheets is to use a macro / VBA for Excel code or JavaScript API for Office. For this, you need to know the spreadsheet structure, know some programming, the Excel version used, and how it's shared, i.e., if you have a single workbook instance hosted in a file-sharing solution like OneDrive, Sharepoint, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc., or if a copy of the workbook is sent to each user.

---

It looks like you are using your workbook as a database, using sheets as filtered views. You are looking for when a status value is changed in one sheet; the conditional formatting is applied to the same record in all views (sheets).

You need to figure out how to update the status for all instances of the same record across all sheets. This will make it a lot easier to set conditional formatting as you are looking. Otherwise, you will need a very complex formula or use code that might be hard to write and maintain. A spreadsheet is not the best software application to handle your use case, but it might be a good option under certain circumstances.

As mentioned above, one way this could be done is by using code. However, other ways require changing the structure of your workbook and how it's being used; this means that you will have to invest time in training the workbook users, and the success of your process might be compromised due to the complexity and the dependence on the users' skills and discipline.

You will have fewer problems using a database like Microsoft Access, a SharePoint list, or one of the online collaboration services available on the Web, among many other possibilities. Considering the question content, I think that it's very likely that your next step might be to post a question in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) for a recommendation. By this, I mean to do an excellent ask-a-good-question process. Please read their [tour](https://softarerecs.stackexcange.com/tour) carefully and [How do I ask a good question?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Sending an Excel file as an attachment creates a copy of the workbook for each recipient. While it's possible to design a solution that works this way to "share" a workbook, it's prone to have problems as there are a lot of dependencies. However, these dependencies are easily handled in a corporate environment, i.e., ensuring all users have the same Excel version and good networking bandwidth, among other things.